# Is there a way call the current function (and it's arguments) again after a Timeout in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, timeout, nodes

Example:

```
function foo(){
setTimeout(/*function(){foo(and all arguments);}*/, 2000);
}
```

Is there any way I can call the same function again after that timeout. The problem I'm having is that the arguments are not strings, but nodes. E.g.:

```
foo(document.body, document.getElementById('header'));
```

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to acheive??

Comment: You are trying to call `foo` iteratively and indefinitely until the page is refreshed?

Comment: Yes, same concept. I'm waiting for a variable to change though.

Comment: What variable are you waiting to change the `header`? There other ways rather than polling, you can use [`Mutation events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events)(now deprecated) or [`Mutation observers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question leads me to think that you are trying to do this

HTML

```
<div id="header"></div>
```

Javascript

```
function foo() {
    setTimeout((function (that, args) {
        return function () {
            foo.apply(that, args);
        };
    }(this, arguments)), 2000);

    console.log(arguments);
}

foo(document.body, document.getElementById('header'));
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/XLjRE/)